# Similar matricies and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Verify this for A and $A = P^{-1}AP$. If y is an eigenvector of P, show that x = Py are eigenvectors of A. Show the details of your work.

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4\\
4 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 2\\
3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$

So I found $P^{-1}AP$ and it equals:

$$P^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix}
-25 & 12\\
-50 & 25
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But I'm not sure what it's asking me in the latter? I know that the eigenvectors of A make up the column vectors of P and that's the special relationship between A and P... but I'm not sure why I need to know the eigenvectors of P. My book says:

[image]

Specifically in theoreum 4 it says:

> Here X is the matrix with these eigenvectors as column vectors.

So why is the book asking me to find the eigenvectors of P?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the eigenvalue equation:
$$AX=\lambda X \implies A P^{-1} P  X= \lambda X \implies (P AP^{-1}) P X= \lambda PX$$
If $B=PAP^{-1}$, then $B ~(PX) =\lambda (PX)$  is the eigenvalue equation for $B$ whose eigenvalues are again $\lambda$ but the eigenvectors are $PX$.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't follow